# Wordpress - create customizer objects from wpdb response

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I have the following code:

```
add_action('customize_register', 'homepage_sections');
//products
function homepage_sections($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_panel('homepage_sections', array(
        'title'             => 'Homepage Sections',
        'priority'          => '20'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_section('homepage_settings_section', array(
        'title'             =>  'Homepage settings',
        'panel'             =>  'homepage_sections',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('homepage_settings_setting', array(
        'default'           =>  1
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('homepage_settings_control', array(
        'section'           =>  'homepage_settings_section',
        'settings'          =>  'homepage_settings_setting',
        'label'             =>  'Number of sections',
        'description'       =>  'Number of sections in homepage',
        'type'              =>  'number'
    ));


    global $wpdb;
    $sections=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT section_id, section_title FROM vt_homepage_sections;');

    foreach($sections as $key){
        $section_id=$key->section_id;
        $cust_setting_id=$section_id.'_setting';
        $cust_control_id=$section_id.'_control';


        $wp_customize->add_setting($cust_setting_id,array(

        ));
        $wp_customize->add_control($cust_control_id,array(
            'settings'          =>  $cust_setting_id,
            'section'           =>  'homepage_settings_section',
            'label'             =>  'test Control'
        ));
    }
}
```

**Issue**
Everything works fine when i don't use variables which contain a value fetched using $wpdb. Is $wpdb object loaded after customizer framework?

When I use the code above, the above customized objects font appear in the customizer panel. Would appreciate hints to what's wrong with my code above.

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 0):

Please try this  like this '$sections = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT section_id, section_title FROM vt_homepage_sections');'

Comment: That's just defining the variable assignment as one whole string though. I'm not sure that would help

Answer (score 0):

define global class at the start of function and check.

Comment: I will be able to try this during the weekend as I'm not working until then. But what effect would that have ? The class is still defined prior to its execution